# How to access AWS public dataset using Databricks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataset, databricks, aws-databricks

For one of my classes, I have to analyze a "big data" dataset. I found the following dataset on the AWS Registry of Open Data that seems interesting:

https://registry.opendata.aws/openaq/

How exactly can I create a connection and load this dataset into Databricks? I've tried the following:

```
df = spark.read.format("text").load("s3://openaq-fetches/")
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Conflicting directory structures detected. Suspicious paths:
```

Also, it seems that this dataset has multiple folders. How do I access a particular folder in Databricks, and if possible, can I focus on a particular time range? Let's say, from 2016 to 2020?

Ultimately, I would like to perform various SQL queries in order to analyze the dataset and perhaps create some visualizations as well. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you'll find that every set of Open Data is in a different format, as provided by the creator of the data. So, one method wouldn't necessarily work with multiple datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [browse the bucket](https://openaq-fetches.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html), you'll see that there are multiple datasets there, in different formats, that will require different access methods.  So you need to point to the specific folder (and maybe its subfolder to load data).  Like, to load `daily` dataset you need to use CSV format:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true")\
   .option("header", "false").load("s3://openaq-fetches/daily/")
```

To load only subset of the data you can use [path filters](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#path-global-filter), for example. See [Spark documentation on loading data](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html).

P.S. the `inferSchema` isn't very optimal from performance standpoint, so it's better to explicitly [provide schema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema) when reading.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense - thanks. If I wanted to access 's3://openaq-fetches/realtime-gzipped/2018-01-01/', what format would I use to read in the data? I've never encountered a file that uses a ndjson.gz format.

Comment: You can use json - ndjson means - new line delimited JSON, exactly format that is expected by Spark